# Busy loop slows down latency-critical computation

Tags: c++, performance, low-latency

My code does the following:

1. Do some long-running intense computation (called *useless* below)
2. Do a small latency-critical task

I find that the time it takes to execute the latency-critical task is higher with the long-running computation than without it.

Here is some stand-alone C++ code to reproduce this effect:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdint.h>

    #define LEN 128
    #define USELESS 1000000000
    //#define USELESS 0

    // Read timestamp counter
    static inline long long get_cycles()
    {
            unsigned low, high;
            unsigned long long val;
            asm volatile ("rdtsc" : "=a" (low), "=d" (high));
            val = high;
            val = (val << 32) | low;
            return val;
    }

    // Compute a simple hash
    static inline uint32_t hash(uint32_t *arr, int n)
    {
            uint32_t ret = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    ret = (ret + (324723947 + arr[i])) ^ 93485734985;
            }
            return ret;
    }

    int main()
    {
            uint32_t sum = 0;       // For adding dependencies
            uint32_t arr[LEN];      // We'll compute the hash of this array

            for(int iter = 0; iter < 3; iter++) {
                    // Create a new array to hash for this iteration
                    for(int i = 0; i < LEN; i++) {
                            arr[i] = (iter + i);
                    }

                    // Do intense computation
                    for(int useless = 0; useless < USELESS; useless++) {
                            sum += (sum + useless) * (sum + useless);
                    }

                    // Do the latency-critical task
                    long long start_cycles = get_cycles() + (sum & 1);
                    sum += hash(arr, LEN);
                    long long end_cycles = get_cycles() + (sum & 1);

                    printf("Iteration %d cycles: %lld\n", iter, end_cycles - start_cycles);
            }
    }
```

When compiled with `-O3` with `USELESS` set to 1 billion, the three iterations took 588, 4184, and 536 cycles, respectively. When compiled with `USELESS` set to 0, the iterations took 394, 358, and 362 cycles, respectively.

Why could this (particularly the 4184 cycles) be happening? I suspected cache misses or branch mis-predictions induced by the intense computation. However, without the intense computation, the zeroth iteration of the latency critical task is pretty fast so I don't think that cold cache/branch predictor is the cause.

Comment: I bet that `get_cycles()` is reordered before the inner loop. Try to look at assembler.

Comment: The 4184 outlier may be caused by something out of your control, like the OS or another process, getting in the way. In addition, rdtsc's accuracy on modern multi-core, multi frequency computers is iffy.

Comment: @Jarod42 - I checked. It's not reordered.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks! Binding the process to a core (and it's memory to a NUMA domain) eliminates the outlier. But the average with USELESS = 1 billion is still higher (520 cycles compared to 360 cycles with USELESS = 0).

Comment: Its possible that while your busy loop is running, other tasks on the server are pushing out the cached `arr` data out of the L1 cache, so that the first memory access in `hash` needs to reload from a lower level cache.  Without the compute loop this wouldn't happen.  You could try moving the `arr` initialization to after the computation loop, just to see what the effect is.

Comment: Hmm.  My tests show that the slowest iteration is always the 3rd (ie iter == 2).  But I can fix it by adding `Sleep(0);` just before the latency critical task.  In fact, all 3 iterations complete faster if I add this (both the latency-critical part AND the entire loop).  I don't understand it, but it seems like a clue.  In an unrelated note, get_cycles can be replaced with `__builtin_ia32_rdtsc();`.  When it comes to inline asm, less is better.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: Thanks! Moving the `arr` initialization to after the computation loop reduces the average to 370 cycles. So it was a cache issue after all.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd Thanks for the `__builtin_ia32_rdtsc()` suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving my speculative comment to an answer:

It is possible that while your busy loop is running, other tasks on the server are pushing the cached `arr` data out of the L1 cache, so that the first memory access in `hash` needs to reload from a lower level cache. Without the compute loop this wouldn't happen. You could try moving the `arr` initialization to after the computation loop, just to see what the effect is.